# Count hour and minutes between multiple dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, count

Is there a function to count the total hour minutes between multiple dates?

I have multiple times like these:

10:00 18:00 | 15:00 23:00 | 00:00 00:00 | 08:30 16:30 | 00:00 00:00 | 16:00 19:00 | 00:00 00:00

As you can see some can be empty, now i need to know the total amount of hours and minutes i worked that week. Does somebody know a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Divide and conquer. Calculate total hours of each day/time slot, then summarize them. Don't try to make problems harder than they are :)

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php and http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: If you have that input as a string first explode("|",$str); to have them in your hand seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example solution including parsing of the input in your question. It does not use the `DateTime` class, but performs a super simple calculation to calculate the total hours.

```
$shifts = "10:00 18:00 | 15:00 23:00 | 00:00 00:00 | 08:30 16:30 | 00:00 00:00 | 16:00 19:00 | 00:00 00:00";
$shifts= explode('|', $shifts);

$sum = 0;    

foreach($shifts as $shift) {
    $times = explode(' ', trim($shift));
    $start = explode(':', $times[0]);
    $end = explode(':', $times[1]);

    $sum += ($end[0] - $start[0]) + ($end[1] - $start[1]) / 100 / 0.6;
}

echo $sum; // prints the result 27
```

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create two new DateTime-objects...
$date1 = new DateTime('2006-04-12T12:30:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2006-04-14T11:30:00');

// The diff-methods returns a new DateInterval-object...
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);

// Call the format method on the DateInterval-object
echo $diff->format('%d Day and %h hours');
```

Comment: i almost got it, but now the gmdate(to go from the total seconds to hours:minutes) won't go above 24 hours..